# reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions handler is called with ErrorReauthorizedFailedReasonUserCancelled

Tags: ios, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using iOS SDK 3.1.1 and trying to get both read and publish permission at once.
As tutorial says, I'm calling FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions and in its handler - handler A - call [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions only if handler A is called with session state of FBSessionStateOpen.

When I have facebook account is set in iOS 6's setting, reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions's handler - handler B - is called normally, with error argument of nil.

However, if I don't have facebook account set in iOS 6's setting, handler B is called with reauth error named "ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonUserCancelled" when app is switched to Safari to gain publish permission.

More weird thing is this. In both cases before handler B is called, handler A is called with session state of FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended.

Are these normal or expected behavior of new SDK? If so, should I not check if error is nil in handler B?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/545891522094555?browse=search_509396c40fa349988430305 reported it to facebook's bugs tracking system

Comment: happens to me too, have you figured out a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

happened to me and after searching a while I found a solution for that. You have to call reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions in `dispatch_async` in the handler A of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                                 defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                   // handle the flow here
                                           }];
});
```

Comment: could u provide a complete sample please ? does the dispatch_async have to be called in completionHandler of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions ?

Comment: yes, you should do this in the completion handler of `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions`